# How to get value of a variable before a loop after loop is executed?

Tags: c, loops

I would like to know if there is a way to get the value of an integer variable before it entered the loop, after the loop has been executed.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  int x;

  x = 1;
  printf("%d\n", x);

  while(x < 2000){
     x++;
    printf("%d\n", x);
  }
  printf("before the loop, X had a value of %d", x);
}
```

Is there a way to have the final `printf()` print the value of `x`which the `x` was holding before entering the `while()` loop? Or is the only way to create a copy of `x` using another variable before the loop?

Comment: Create a copy. You are after all modifying the value of `x` inside the loop

Comment: There is not. It would be incredibly expensive for the computer to store every value that a variable has held within a program. It's much cheaper just to make a copy of `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the abstract context you would typically have two options:

1. "Think ahead" approach: store the original value beforehand, i.e. create a copy before applying any modifications to the original value.
2. "Turn back time" approach: use the new value as a starting point to "revert" all modifications and thus arrive at the original value.

In general case there are trade-offs associated with each approach.

Applied to your specific simple example, these two approaches involve either storing the copy of the variable before the loop, or "undoing" the changes done by the loop (by using your intimate knowledge of this loop's semantics). The latter in this case boils down to

```
printf("before the loop, X had a value of %d", x - 1999);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no *magical* way to get the *initial* (any previous state, for that matter) value of a variable, once it is modified. You have to create (maintain) a copy yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the old value before the loop to another variable:

```
int x;
int old_x;

x = 1;
printf("%d\n", x);

old_x = x;
while(x < 2000){
   x++;
  printf("%d\n", x);
}
printf("before the loop, X had a value of %d", old_x);
```

Or vice versa,  use different variable forthe loop and keep original untouched.

There is no magic the compiler could do it for you.